# Hystrix vs MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager

Tags: java, spring, hystrix

we have a web page implemented using SpringMVC+JSP. To get the data needed on each page we call an external API. The summary of steps are:
- Request arrives to a controller
- A call to the API is made to retrieve data
- Data is added to the JSP view-model and returned to the user.

To call the API we are using RestTemplate using `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` initialized with connection and read timeout. If the API is unavailable the RestTemplate throws exceptions that are handled by the controller of the web page.

Lately I was reading about Hytrix and seems it is used make requests among systems.
I request for some explanation on how Hytrix can help on our system and how to integrate it.

In addition, the API implementation retrieves data from different sources, one of them a database. Can Hytrix help also on a scenario where database is down?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Hystrix does not make the requests among systems. It wraps your request code to get *observed* (timeouts, error counts) and provides circuit breaker to stop your application creating calls again 'dead' systems (remote service or even a database).

**Slightly longer answer**

Hystrix is a thin wrapper between your service and persistence / remote service layer (from now on just persistence) (I think this is the most common use case). Instead of calling your persistence from the service directly you are creating a new HystrixCommand that contains the acutal persistence call. This command is highly customizable and provides mechanisms for Timeouts and Circuit breakers out-of-the-box. If your call times out or generates to much exceptions it will switch to a fallback implementation you may (and should) implement. So it's up to your use case if a fallback could also help in case of a database downtime (maybe something like using cached data).
As a side-effect you also get statistics for your calls: Error count, percentage, amount of calls...

A month ago I started using HystrixCommands (and Collapsers) and [made a blog post](http://meistermeier.com/java/hystrix/2015/01/28/hystrix-to-the-rescue.html) about Hystrix and interface communication in general that might give you additional informations (or confusions ;) )